# Is "pointer->register_next->value" the same as "pointer->register_next.value" in C?

Tags: c, pointers, search

I'm studying searching procedures in lists (C language), and I've seen procedures use both the *arrow operator* and the *dot operator* when writing conditions.

For a **struct** like...

```
struct node{
  int value; //value, can be any type
  struct node *next;
};
```

I've seen...

```
if(current->next->value == searched_value)
```

...and

```
if(current->next.value == searched_value)
```

...being used. My question is: *Are are these method interchangeable in any given case?* (i.e they are the same)

Comment: Can you provide a compilable example? You usually get an compiler error if you choose the wrong operator.

Comment: Your second example is not valid and will not compile.

Comment: If you've never used something like [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), I highly suggest to start immediately. It'll provide instant answers to such questions in less time it'd take you to type your question. Had you used the explorer, you'd immediately know that only one of the variants you provide is syntactically correct - so it's very much worth to always have godbolt open when you code :) Also: the  question doesn't have much to do with CPU registers, just as talking about a database of cars wouldn't make it an automotive question :)

Comment: When accessing struct members, the `'->'` (arrow) operator is used to dereference a *pointer to struct* to access the member. When dealing with a struct itself the `'.'` (dot) operator is used to access its member.

Comment: "*For a struct like...
...
I've seen...

...and ...*" you most likely have not, at least no code which compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@PabloSantaCruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67606/pablo-santa-cruz) correctly notes, accessing members of a struct using `'->'` and `'.'` are very much not the same.

To know which to use, you simply have to answer the question of **"Do I have a struct or pointer to struct?"**

When accessing struct members, the `'->'` (arrow) operator is used to dereference a *pointer to struct* to access the members. When dealing with a struct itself the `'.'` (dot) operator is used to access its members.

There is nothing better than practice and an example to help compare/contrast the usage, for example, the following declares an array of struct to serve as your list, where each element is a struct. To simply access the members of each element all that is needed is the dot operator. However, to show how they are related, if you take the address of each element, thereby creating a pointer to it, the arrow operator can be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

int main (void) {

    struct node list[2] = {{1, &list[1]}, {2, NULL}},   /* array */
                *l = list;  /* pointer to first element */

    puts ("\nusing list, e.g. list[0].val\n");      /* the dot operator */
    printf (" %d %d\n", list[0].val, list[1].val);

    /* taking the address of each element and using the arrow operator */
    puts ("\nusing address of each list element, e.g. (&list[0])->val\n");
    printf (" %d %d\n", (&list[0])->val, (&list[1])->val);

    puts ("\nusing l, e.g. l->val\n");  /* using the pointer & arrow op. */
    printf (" %d %d\n", l->val, (l + 1)->val);

    puts ("\ntraversing list using l\n"); /* traversing with the pointer */
    while (l) {
        printf (" %d", l->val);
        l = l->next;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

In each case above, you simply answer the question *"Do I have a struct or pointer to struct?"* to know which operator to use.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_array

using list, e.g. list[0].val

 1 2

using address of each list element, e.g. (&list[0])->val

 1 2

using l, e.g. l->val

 1 2

traversing list using l

 1 2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

No. They're definitely not the same and they are not interchangeable.

The arrow operator `->` only works when you have a pointer to a struct as a variable.

So:

```
struct *p;
p->a = 0; // correct
p.a = 0; //syntax error
```

Clearly you must have been looking something else, because if `next`  is of `struct node *` type (a pointer to `struct node`) then, `current->next.value`  is an error.

In `gcc`  you should get an error saying: `error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union`

Comment: I may have made a mistake, the original two structures was a register of a person(with an _int_ and a _char_ variable), and a list (with a _struct person_ and a _struct list *next_ variable). Would it work in that case, or would the conditions mean something completely different? The conditions being (if (current->next->value->int == searched_value) and if(current->next->value.int == searched_value)

Answer (score 1):

`current->next->value` can also be written `(*(*current).next).value)`.

The reason you need those parenthesis is that `.` has higher precedence than `*`. The `->` is basically just syntactic sugar to reduce the amount of parenthesis.

> Are are these method interchangeable in any given case?

In a way yes. You can always use dots instead of arrows if you use parenthesis the proper way. You can also go the other way. This code compiles without warnings and prints `1 2 3 4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int foo; 
  int bar;
} myStruct;

int main() {
    myStruct a;
    (&a)->foo = 1;
    a.bar = 2;

    myStruct * b = malloc(sizeof *b);
    b->foo = 3;
    (*b).bar = 4;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a.foo, (&a)->bar, (*b).foo, b->bar);
}
```

The `->` operator requires the left operator to be a pointer, while `.` requires it to not be a pointer. But as you can see, dereferencering a pointer (using `*`) gives you the data the pointer is pointing at, and thus you can use `.` instead. And using `&` gives you the address of the object, which enforces the use of `->` instead of `.`.

In practice, this should never be an issue. Choose the most convenient, and I cannot think of an example where I would not know which to choose.

Actually, this is related to the `[]` operator, which you are using for indexing arrays. That is also just syntactic sugar. The expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`. This has the funny consequence that `a[i]` is actually the same as `i[a]`.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but why did you ask for the address of foo when printing? (in &foo->foobar). I thought you only needed it in scanf().

Comment: @Chabon Only to show that it is possible. I fixed a small bug btw.

Comment: Also, does that mean that you can use "->" to access the pointer to the next node, then to the next, then to the next (ad infinitum) _and then_ to the register and it's subsequent value? <For example, "my_node->next->next->next->next->register->value", closing the "->" chain_ with the value, obviusly. Or is there something that prevents me from doing that?

Comment: @Chabon I don't know if there is a depth limit.